# Where can I find Ruby's parse.y file on my system?

Tags: ruby, parsing, bison

I'm reading about how Ruby is parsed and compiled, and I'd like to see the parse.y file that's being used. I haven't managed to find it anywhere on my system (OS X). I've tried `find / -name parse.y` without any luck.

Running `ruby -y myfile.rb` shows line numbers within parse.y being used, which makes me think it does exist somewhere, I just don't know where. I've looked at [parse.y online](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y), but I'd like to see my local copy.

For example, given:

```
# myfile.rb
puts 'hi'
```

When I run `ruby -y myfile.rb`, I see:

```
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 859):
...
```

I've been assuming line numbers, like 859 above, are referring to lines within parse.y. Is that not the case?

Comment: Why do you assume there *is* a local copy? Ruby does not refer to its own source-code when executing a Ruby file. Ruby is a compiled binary.

Comment: @meagar If that's the case, where do the line numbers come from when I run `ruby -y myfile.rb`?

Comment: The presence of line numbers is not necessarily indicative that Ruby is somehow reading `parse.y` off disk. Nobody ships their source code with the binary for this purpose, the source code is simply compiled with judicious use of `__LINE__`.

Comment: @meagar Ah, well that makes a lot more sense then. Thanks. If you want to make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`parse.y`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y) belongs to the Ruby source code. When you install Ruby on your machine, the source code is compiled into the Ruby interpreter therefore, unless you keep the compilation artifacts, you don't get access to the single `parse.y` file.

Moreover, the `parse.y` file is not different at all than the file used by your specific Ruby version at compilation time. You can search for your version in the ufficial Ruby repository and read the file from there.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't state which Ruby implementation you are using. Not all Ruby implementations use Bison to generate the parser. Not all Ruby implementations are even capable of executing C code, which is what Bison generates. XRuby used ANTLR, for example. JRuby uses a parser that is hand-translated to Java from `parse.c`, i.e. the *generated* C code which is generated by Bison from `parse.y`.

Of those Ruby implementations that *do* use Bison, none ships `parse.y`. It is source code, after all, not part of the binary. In fact, during compilation `parse.y` first gets compiled to C, which then gets compiled together with the rest of the implementation into a binary, and *that* binary is what is shipped.

If you want to know which exact `parse.y` file was used to compile your Ruby executable, you will have to ask whoever compiled your Ruby executable. Provided that the Ruby implementation you are using even uses `parse.y` at all.